# a link in my website does not redirect to the specified path

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

">read More

I have the above link in my website news page so these links are supposed to redirect to the expanded news page. These links works well in my localhost however when i deployed my site in the server these links redirects to the index.php page.
As you can see the href attribute, it points towards "news_expanded" page but when i click on it, how does it redirect me to the index.php file ?

Comment: You need to add forward flash in your link. Or need to specify home url.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a slash (/) in front of your URL. That should fix the problem.

Comment: it works well in my localhost so how adding a slash in front of the url will solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried? A slash can help redirect the browser to the main domain and then to the address e.g. foo.php

Answer (score 1):

It is very important to start URLs with `/` when you are going to change structure of you site.

For example, if you are on `/test` page and then you have link on this page is `testing`. When you click on this link it will redirect to `/test/testing` instead of `/testing`. So that means it will consider as child page of current page. So forward slash intended URL is returned instead of its parent or child.

So it is good practice to all forward slash in all links or you can specify you site URL as a constant and add this constant value like below:

Define constant in common file like this `define('SITE_URL','http://example.com/');`

Use like below

```
<a class="read_more_wrapper" href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>news_expanded.php?news_id=<?php echo $record['news_id']; ?>"><button class="read-more">read More</button></a>
```

Or just add forward slash like this

```
<a class="read_more_wrapper" href="/news_expanded.php?news_id=<?php echo $record['news_id']; ?>"><button class="read-more">read More</button></a>
```

Comment: tried both of those ways. neither of them worked. When i hover over the link it shows the correct path as in the server file structure. but when i click it takes me to index page.

Comment: @KeenDesign then you need to check your htaccess file if source on linux.